# css - container div fit content to image

Tags: image, css

I'm wondering if it is possible to specify a div (example div2) or another sourrounding element of an image to fit the height and width to its child.
Besides, the image should resize (keep aspect ratio) to the full available space (div1) of the div2's parent.

As the image and therefore the aspect ratio, image orientation, hieght and width can change dynamically, no fixed sizing is possible

Here is an example fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rp7u3u2r/1/

```
<div style="width:200px; height: 200px;">
    <div style="max-height: 100%;max-width:100%;">
        <img style="max-height: 100%;max-width: 100%;" src="..."/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Expected behavior:
[image: Fit div2 to img]

I already tried 'object-fit', 'fit-content', 'display: table-cell', 'display: inline-block', but nothing seems to work as expected.

Comment: Why though? Can't you just put a green border on the image? Please explain the need for this markup - perhaps there's some other way to achieve what you need.

Comment: First of all, I need to put an overlay over the image with the same size. Secondly, both, the image and the overlay must been able to react on the same mouse click events. And as another point, the overlay and the image should been able to beeing zoomed with webkit-transform. The easiest way would be to have a sourrounding, fitting element around both, the overlay and the div, on which the transformation can be executed

Comment: When the outer div must have a fixed width and height, why you don't give this not to the image ? This should resolve the problems.

Comment: That's right., I uncleared my question a little bit. Unfortunately the container has also percentual sizes and no fixed size :-(

Answer (score 0):

updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rp7u3u2r/3/

```
<div style="background-color:red; width:200px; height: 200px; font-size:0; line-height: 0;">
    <div style="background-color: green; display: inline-block;">
        <img style="width: auto; height: auto; max-height: 200px;max-width: 200px;"
        src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Bonsai_IMG_6426.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: COMMENT: the line-height:0 and font-size:0 is to prevent the divs from taking extra space

Answer (score 0):

Use these styles:

```
#div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#div2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Both `div2` and `img` will be constrained to the height of `div1`.

`box-sizing` allows you to add border and padding to `div2` without overflowing `div1`.

### Fiddle